# Multiplexer CD74HC4051, always giving a true out

Tags: arduino, multiplexer

I'm testing a multiplexer from Texas Instruments (CD74HC4051). Both +5V and Ground rails are connected to the Arduino Duemilanove board.

I've got a +5V signal in the channel A7 (pin4) and A0 (pin 13), moving my address selectors to different addresses than A0 and A7 still keeps the output active.

When dashing through all the 8 addresses, the output is basically always +5V.

**How come?**

The images below are: the CD74HC4051 pinout, my setup connections, and the 4051 truth table. The photos at the end of the post show three different address configurations.

**CD74HC4051 Pinout:**

[image: CD74HC4051 Pinout]

**Setup connections:**

[image: Setup connections]

[image]

**Photo 1 - Address False, False, False:**
[image: Setup with address False, False, False]

**Photo 2 - Address True, False, False:**
[image: Setup with address True, False, False]

**Photo 3 - Address True, True, True:**
[image: Setup with address True, True, True]

Below is the schematics with the pull down resistors. This solves the impedance issue of the IC pin internal resistance and possible noise and float signal to the pin.

[image: Schematics with the pull down resistors]

Comment: What is the intent of the last three photos? They appear to be the same.

Comment: The address selectors have changed: FFF, TFF, TTT

Comment: In the photos it seems like the DIP switches connect to 5V when closed, but leave S0-S2 floating when open. Is that correct? If yes, you need pulldown resistors.

Comment: @fmunkert, I've included 3 pull down resistors (1000ohms) for each selector pin, and it's working. Thanks

Comment: the resistor are 1000 ohms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being CMOS, you need to make sure that all of the address inputs are either connected to Vcc or GND since once you charge up the gate capacitances of the decoder's input MOSFETs they'll stay charged up for a long time when the address dip switches go open-circuit.

I don't see any pull-downs on the chip side of your address dip switch, so you need to connect about 10k from each of them to GND.